# Unable to add new tags on creation of new test case using rally rest api and java

Tags: java, rest, api, rally

I am using the below code to add tags in tags field ,  on creating new test case using rally rest api(JAVA).
But tags are not added to the tag field in rally. Please help me out.

```
    String tags = "@tag1 ,@tag2";
    JsonArray testcases = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject newtestcase = new JsonObject();
    newTestCase.addProperty("Name" , TestCaseName);
    newTestCase.addProperty("Method" , Manual);
    JsonArray arr1= new JsonArray();
    arr1.add(tags);
    newTestCase.addProperty("Tags" , tags);
  Createrequest createrequest = new Createrequest("TestCase" , newTestCase);
    JsonObject testcase = new JsonObject();
    testcase.addProperty("_ref" , ref);
    testcases.add(testcase);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference tags by their ref, just like any other object in WSAPI.

```
JsonArray tags = new JsonArray();

JsonObject tag1 = new JsonObject();
tag1.addProperty("_ref", "/tag/12345");
tags.add(tag1);

JsonObject tag2 = new JsonObject();
tag2.addProperty("_ref", "/tag/23456");
tags.add(tag2);

newTestcase.addProperty("Tags", tags);
```

Comment: In the ref link : /tag/12345  , 12345 is the object id of the tag , so please let me know , how to add the tag with tag name

Comment: correct.  you can't add tags by name.  you'll have to do a query first for tags by name, and then use their refs.

Comment: Hi Kyle Morse , Thanks , the above approach is working for already existing tags .Using the "/tag/12345" , I am able to re-use the available tag for test case.  Please let me know , how to create new tags in creation of new test case.

Comment: There's no way to do it in one step.  You'll have to create the tags first and then reference them in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Morse , I am able to add tag with tag name

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the below steps to create tags by using tag name**

First Create tag separately by using below url with post method

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/tag/create
```

Use the below tag structure to perform post request

```
{"Tag:{"Name": "@tag1"}}
```

Reference object will be created for tags. U can use the ref url of tag(/tag/12345) , and add it in test case